# Prompt return as undefined in a function. (scope issue)

Tags: javascript, function, scope, undefined, prompt

I believe it's a scope issue because I tried setting my function `userPrmpt` inside `firstPartCook` and it works. I set it outside, and it doesn't. So it's reading, but not keeping what is returned. I thought by placing it in the test var that it would work, but it doesn't.

Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Race Makin' </title>
  <!-- Link to the JS portion for this script -->
  <script src="riceMakin.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- not going for anything fancy. Just focusing on mechanics -->
  <h1>Lets cook some damn rice</h1>
  <h2> To start cooking Rice, please hit start</h2>
  <button onclick="firstPartCook()">Start</button>
  <h3>Below explains the status on the Rice Making Machine:</h3>
  <!-- with JS i have what is inbetween the spans, switching from on and off -->
  <p id="print">Status: Turned <span id="print">Off</span> </p>     
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```js
//Global Vars here
//Promp for the User to continue throught the script. To use what is returned, set to a var
function userPrmpt(userResponse) {
   prompt(userResponse);
}

// This function is for adding type to the DOM.
function insertCopy (copy) {
   var paragraphCreate = document.createElement("p");
   var copyNode = document.createTextNode(copy);
   paragraphCreate.appendChild(copyNode);
   var idSelecter = document.getElementById("print");
   //print is the id tag of the span 
   idSelecter.appendChild(paragraphCreate);
}

//This is where we start working on the mechanics of the script    
function firstPartCook() {
   //var userAnswer = prompt("Welcome to the Rice Maker, want to start making rice?");
   var test = userPrmpt("Hello");
   if (test == "yes") {
      console.log(test);
      insertCopy("It worked");
   } else {
      console.log(test);
      insertCopy("Nope");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the value from the prompt, otherwise the function will just return `undefined`, which is the default return value of any function that has no other value returned from it

```
function userPrmpt(userResponse){
    return prompt(userResponse);
}
```

Comment: Wow hahaha. Thanks man. The simplest things in coding are the most annoying issues to find. Thanks again!