# setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0); it has value 0

Tags: javascript, function

When I execute the below code in the console I am getting as:

`1,4, undefined 3,2.`

I would like to know why its not executing as `1,3,4` and `2`
since in `setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0);` the milliseconds param is `0`.

```
(function() {
   console.log(1); 
   setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 1000); 
   setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0); 
   console.log(4);
})();
```

Comment: the `undefined` is from the console, it's the return of the execution of the function, not outputted with console.log

Comment: it's returning 1,4,3,2  because when you use setTimeout you put the code to run in another thread

Comment: Ok, missed the point of *Code entered directly in Console input*. Otherwise  on a page that script will never log `undefined`.

Comment: Closed as duplicate cause there is explained really well what's actually going on. **Read all the comments and all answers** cause the accepted answer is not properly getting to the point of Browser queue.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This was not the point of the question.. and there is no accepted answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan and I am getting this point if you read the decomposition.

Comment: @Hacketo **that's exactly the point of the question!**. Question 1. is answered simply by knowing *defacto* that calls of functions that are executed with no `return` value lead to `undefined` (console run only and parse-time silent). Question 2. and 3. are all  about `setTimeout`; *in short* another way to stack executions to the window events queue, almost exactly like `DOMContentLoaded` does, therefore the (*un-*)expected result are thrown - lately stack after the `window.console` stack. All explained in the other question comments and answers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I thought all the points (1,2,3) were questions .. mb

Comment: @Hacketo majority wins. If you want I can close it again as duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975899/prompt-return-as-undefined-in-a-function-scope-issue :) Yes, those [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) answer all the OP questions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I edited the question as it should be formatted. make more sense, ianaya89 did not edit that part of the formatting ...

Comment: @Hacketo waiting for anyone to reopen the question so I can write an extensive answer with all the technical documentation and details. making it than actually a duplicate of all the already provided answers on SO on that topic (I've mentioned above the related links (and there's even more)). Or rather let's keep it closed since it is actually a dupe since the `setTimeout` stack feature

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not, I formatted the question properly , now it make more sense that is focused on Browser queue, see this [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28115853/2) that maked 3 questions

Answer (score 6):

Here's a great explanation by John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

But the bottom line is `console.log(1)` and `(4)` are executed 'in-line' and `2` and `3` are placed in the event queue, and don't get executed until the all of the in-line code is executed.  So, even though the delay is `0` for `(3)`, it still occurs after all statements are executed.

I'm not getting the `undefined` message when I test your code either.

Answer (score 4):

The `undefined` is, as mentioned in a comment, the return value of your function.

The reason why `4` comes before `3` is simply that there is no parallelism in JavaScript so the timer callbacks cannot execute until your function has returned.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: the `undefined` comes from the result of the executed statement in your JavaScript console, the function return nothing, so `undefined`

Let try to decompose this:

1. `console.log(1);` // `1`
2. `console.log(4);` // `4`
3. the code you executed return `undefined`
4. `setTimeout(function(){console.log(3)}, 0);` // `3` Executed the next stack
5. `setTimeout(function(){console.log(2)}, 1000);`  // `2` 1 sec after

Edit: test this

```
var a = (function(){})(); // print undefined, a is also undefined, no returned value
```